# AWS Pinpoint usage analytics, with Cognito hosted UI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-pinpoint

I want to connect Pinpoint to my Cognito User Pool. My only requirement as of now is to see usage analytics, like new users, daily active users, etc. I created a Pinpoint project, then inside the user pool, went to General settings > Analytics > Add Analytics, selected the Cognito app client, selected the Pinpoint project in to corresponding region, checked the 'Share user profile data' checkbox. I have added Hosted UI for my cognito user pool, and signing up new users from there. However I don't get any analytics data at all in my pinpont usage dashboard. Am I missing something, is it not possible to do it via hosted UI?

Comment: It takes a while for the events to be shown on the analytics dashboard in AWS COnsole. Did you do any new signups so that the data will be pushed.

Comment: Yes I have made 6 signups, signed in with a few of them, it's been more than 2 days but still no data is showing up